# Error installing google chrome package

Tags: apt, google-chrome

Actually the error occurs with anything I try to install, but when the s`udo apt-get install google-chrome-stable` install command is given, this error comes up:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript spice-vdagent, action "restart" failed.
● spice-vdagentd.service - Agent daemon for Spice guests
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/spice-vdagentd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-02-12 10:57:44 -03; 5ms ago
  Process: 15881 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/spice-vdagentd $SPICE_VDAGENTD_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 15880 ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

fev 12 10:57:44 shinier01 systemd[1]: Starting Agent daemon for Spice guests...
fev 12 10:57:44 shinier01 spice-vdagentd[15881]: bind /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock: No such file or directory
fev 12 10:57:44 shinier01 spice-vdagentd[15881]: Fatal could not create server socket /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock
fev 12 10:57:44 shinier01 systemd[1]: spice-vdagentd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
fev 12 10:57:44 shinier01 systemd[1]: spice-vdagentd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
fev 12 10:57:44 shinier01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Agent daemon for Spice guests.
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote spice-vdagent (--configure):
 installed spice-vdagent package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 spice-vdagent
```

I already tried the commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install --reinstall 
rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
apt-get update
apt-get -f install && dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
```

but nothing solves, can someone help me, talking about how to remove this error from spice-vdagentd?

Comment: I am confused what does spice have to do with google chrome?

Comment: Read your output: It's not surprising that random package-management commands don't help, since your output clearly shows that you don't have a package-management problem. You output also clearly shows your starting point for troubleshooting the problem: `bind /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock: No such file or directory`. Ask yourself: Why is it missing?

Comment: I saw in the error output that the folder or file is missing, but I don't know how to correct the lack of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with apt allways giving this error when trying to install something.

I was able to fix it by creating the directory it was complaining about:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/spice-vdagentd
```